# Windows 7 Logon Screen - Not showing any users

Tags: windows-7, login

I've just installed the Windows Home Server 2011 connector.

After restarting at the prompt, Windows tries to log in as user "*clientsetup*$" and there are no other user tiles present when I switch user.

I can still logon manually by pressing the "Other User" tile.

How can I restore the default Logon behavior?

Comment: You might have the same issues with registry keys as me: http://superuser.com/questions/751034/list-of-user-icons-on-logon-screen-has-disappeared