# List of user icons on logon screen has disappeared

Tags: windows-7, login, fast-user-switching

The list of users one can click to log in from the login screen has disappeared. This is what I have done so far:

My C:\Users folder was in reality a NTFS Junction that pointed to D:\Users, so when D:\ was unavailable due to a temporary hardware problem, I got into some problems with my setup.

After

- removing the junction pointing to the other volume
- copying all the profiles back into C:\Users
- mucking around in the Registry in the HKLM.../Windows NT/CurrentVersion/ProfileList and reverting any profiles that had gotten a .bak postfix
- setting the "Flags", "RefCount" and "State" values to 0 in the same key (I only did this on my own user accounts - not all)

logging in finally worked as before.

With one difference.

*The login screen no longer showed the list of available users*! Previously I could just select an icon, but now there is only an icon for the last logged in user, as well as "Other user". I have tried many tips so far, most of which involve fiddling with config settings available through `gpedit.msc`. Any tips on how I could restore the easy login that is the standard?

I wonder if I could delete any of the other register keys in ProfileList. Any clues?

Comment: Have you started to use Active Directory users rather than local ones?

Comment: Njetski - no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete all superfluous profiles in ProfileList. The changes you did might have left some corrupted ones. Refer to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/132832/321304) for more complete explanation and details.

Comment: That was it! I exported the whole ProfileList key with all its subkeys so that I could later revert the change if needed. I then deleted every profile in the list, except my own and the other users. Upon reboot the list of icons was back!